# ST_MAKELINE discarding duplicate points even if not consecutive

Tags: google-bigquery, gis

Consider this simplified example:

```
SELECT ST_MAKELINE([
  ST_GEOGPOINT(5, 51),
  ST_GEOGPOINT(5, 52),
  ST_GEOGPOINT(5, 51)
])
```

I would expect this to construct a line with three points, that doubles back on itself. Instead, what I'm getting is:

```
LINESTRING(5 51, 5 52)
```

It seems that BigQuery is discarding duplicate points, even if they are not consecutive. This is messing up my distance calculation, which involves taking the `ST_LENGTH` of the resulting linestring.

As a workaround, I'm constructing a series of linestrings, each of two consecutive points, then summing the distance of those. But it's awkward and verbose.

Is there a way to create the linestring without dropping duplicate points?

Comment: Documented Constaints: Every edge must span strictly less than 180 degrees.

NOTE: BigQuery's snapping process may discard sufficiently short edges and snap the two endpoints together. For instance, if two input GEOGRAPHYs each contain a point and the two points are separated by a distance less than the snap radius, the points will be snapped together. In such a case the result will be a GEOGRAPHY with exactly one point.

Comment: Exactly: it only talks about _edges_. Neither of my two edges are particularly short.

Comment: @Thomas - i don't think your workaround is actually workaround and rather exactly how you should of approach such cases in BigQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is BigQuery GIS discards duplicate overlapping edges (not vertices).

E.g. you can have line string A, B, C, A and if A, B, and C are not on a single line, nothing is discarded, A is present twice in the line. But if two edges exactly overlap - the overlapping section is discarded.

On the other hand, here there are no duplicate vertices, but second edge completely overlaps the first one, so it is ignored:

```
SELECT ST_MAKELINE([
  ST_GEOGPOINT(5, 51),
  ST_GEOGPOINT(5, 53),
  ST_GEOGPOINT(5, 52)
])

LINESTRING(5 51, 5 52, 5 53)
```

There is currently no way to avoid this behavior - BigQuery Geography represents a point set, and as sets go, when you union two identical sets you get just one copy of this set.