# Query times out after 6 hours, how to optimize it?

Tags: google-bigquery, gis, cartesian-product

I have two tables, `shapes` and `squares`, that I'm joining based on intersections of `GEOGRAHPY` columns.

The `shapes` table contains travel routes for vehicles:

```
shape_key        STRING            identifier for the shape
shape_lines      ARRAY<GEOGRAPHY>  consecutive line segments making up the shape
shape_geography  GEOGRAPHY         the union of all shape_lines
shape_length_km  FLOAT64           length of the shape in kilometers

Rows: 65k
Size: 718 MB
```

We keep `shape_lines` separated out in an `ARRAY` because shapes sometimes double back on themselves, and we want to keep those line segments separate instead of [deduplicating them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58234223/st-makeline-discarding-duplicate-points-even-if-not-consecutive).

The `squares` table contains a grid of 1×1 km squares:

```
square_key        INT64      identifier of the grid square
square_geography  GEOGRAPHY  four-cornered polygon describing the grid square

Rows: 102k
Size: 15 MB
```

The shapes represent travel routes for vehicles. For each shape, we have computed emissions of harmful substances in a separate table. The aim is to calculate the emissions per grid square, assuming that they are evenly distributed along the route. To that end, we need to know what portion of the route shape intersects with each grid cell.

Here's the query to compute that:

```
SELECT
  shape_key,
  square_key,
  SAFE_DIVIDE(
      (
        SELECT SUM(ST_LENGTH(ST_INTERSECTION(line, square_geography))) / 1000
        FROM UNNEST(shape_lines) AS line
      ),
      shape_length_km)
    AS square_portion
FROM
  shapes,
  squares
WHERE
  ST_INTERSECTS(shape_geography, square_geography)
```

Sadly, this query times out after 6 hours instead of producing a useful result.

In the worst case, the query can produce 6.6 billion rows, but that will not happen in practice. I estimate that each shape typically intersects maybe 50 grid squares, so the output should be around 65k * 50 = 3.3M rows; nothing that BigQuery shouldn't be able to handle.

I have considered [the geographic join optimizations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-data#using_joins_with_spatial_data) performed by BigQuery:

- > Spatial JOINs are joins of two tables with a predicate geographic function in the `WHERE` clause.

  Check. I even rewrote my `INNER JOIN` to the equivalent "comma" join shown above.
- > Spatial joins perform better when your geography data is persisted.

  Check. Both `shape_geography` and `square_geography` come straight from existing tables.
- > BigQuery implements optimized spatial JOINs for INNER JOIN and CROSS JOIN operators with the following standard SQL predicate functions: [...] `ST_Intersects`

  Check. Just a single `ST_Intersect` call, no other conditions.
- > Spatial joins are not optimized: for LEFT, RIGHT or FULL OUTER joins; in cases involving ANTI joins; when the spatial predicate is negated.

  Check. None of these cases apply.

So I think BigQuery should be able to optimize this join using whatever spatial indexing data structures it uses.

I have also considered the [advice about cross joins](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-patterns#cross_joins_cartesian_product):

- > Avoid joins that generate more outputs than inputs.

  This query definitely generates more outputs than inputs; that's in its nature and cannot be avoided.
- > When a `CROSS JOIN` is required, pre-aggregate your data.
  >
  > To avoid performance issues associated with joins that generate more outputs than inputs:
  >
  > - Use a GROUP BY clause to pre-aggregate the data.

  Check. I already pre-aggregated the emissions data grouped by shapes, so that each shape in the `shapes` table is unique and distinct.
- > - Use a window function. Window functions are often more efficient than using a cross join. For more information, see [analytic functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#analytic-functions).

  I don't think it's possible to use a window function for this query.

I suspect that BigQuery allocates resources based on the number of input rows, not on the size of the intermediate tables or output. That would explain the pathological behaviour I'm seeing.

How can I make this query run in reasonable time?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the tables? I would like to reproduce it

Comment: @rmesteves Thank you. I've granted `bigquery.dataViewer` access to `allUsers`, hoping that's enough. The names of the tables are `open-transport-data.public.shapes` and `open-transport-data.public.squares`.

Comment: A comma is a `CROSS JOIN` - that is probably breaking your query

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann Of course it's a cross join. Like I said, it's the nature of the beast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `squares` got inverted, resulting in almost-full Earth polygons:

```
select st_area(square_geography), * from   `open-transport-data.public.squares`
```

Prints results like `5.1E14` - which is full globe area. So any line intersects almost all the squares. See BigQuery doc for details : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-data#polygon_orientation

You can invert them by running `ST_GeogFromText(wkt, FALSE)` - which chooses smaller polygon, ignoring polygon orientation, this works reasonably fast:

```
SELECT
  shape_key,
  square_key,
  SAFE_DIVIDE(
      (
        SELECT SUM(ST_LENGTH(ST_INTERSECTION(line, square_geography))) / 1000
        FROM UNNEST(shape_lines) AS line
      ),
      shape_length_km)
    AS square_portion
FROM
  `open-transport-data.public.shapes`,
  (select 
       square_key, 
       st_geogfromtext(st_astext(square_geography), FALSE) as square_geography,
     from `open-transport-data.public.squares`) squares
WHERE
  ST_INTERSECTS(shape_geography, square_geography)
```

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you so much! I'm going to have some stern words with QGIS now, because the CSV-with-WKT export where these squares came from seems to contain right-handed polygons even though WKT is supposed to be using the left-hand rule.

Answer (score 1):

Below would definitely not fit the comments format so I have to post this as an answer ...

I did three adjustment to your query

- using JOIN ... ON instead of CROSS JOIN ... WHERE
- commenting out `square_portion` calculation
- using destination table with `Allow Large Results` option

Even though you expected just 3.3 M rows in output  - in reality it is about  6.6 B ( 6,591,549,944) rows - you can see result of my experiment below

[image]

Note warning about Billing Tier - so you better use Reservations if available
Obviously, un-commenting `square_portion` calculation will increase Slots usage - so, you might potentially need to revisit your requirements/expectations

Comment: Thanks for the thorough investigation! 6.6B output rows means we're getting a full Cartesian product... that's not what I intended. I'll take a closer look at the data tomorrow.